# how to retrieve data from text file in java script using json

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I made a text using named as json_demo.text now i'm trying to retrive the data of this text file

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":31,
    "pets":[
        { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
        { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
        { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
    ]
}//**json_demo.txt**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using Ajax. Example:

> $.ajax({
>               url: "./json_demo.txt",
>               async: false,
>               success: function (data){
>
> ```
>         }
>     })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Rename file to `.json` and place it in same folder as of your project.

Now make an Ajax request to file with relative path as URL. Like `./file.json`.

```
$.ajax({
  url : './file.json',
  method : 'POST', 
  success : function(resp){
    data = JSON.parse(resp.data);
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First store it in a variable.

```
var mydata = 
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":31,
    "pets":[
        { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
        { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
        { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
    ]
}//**json_demo.txt**
```

Now you can access it inside javascript with the variable mydata:

```
alert('I love' + mydata.pets.animal);
```

Using AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        async: false,
        url: 'json_demo.text', /*file location*/
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            /*Do something with data*/
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     fetch(url)
      .then((resp) => resp.text()) // you can use resp.json() for json
      .then(function(data) {
         // data handling
        })
      })
     .catch(function(error) {
    // If there is any error you will catch them here
  });
```